# The Client ID submitted in your add-in package does not match the Client ID submitted via the Seller Dashboard

Tags: office-365, solution-package, provider-hosted-app, seller-dashboard, app-store

I have registered my Provider Hosted Add-in to Microsoft Seller Dashboard. Microsoft has send back a report with this error:

> The Client ID submitted in your add-in package does not match the
>   Client ID submitted via the Seller Dashboard.
>   **Add-in Package:** "1234eb5a-4591-47d0-b006-d94b67b45678”
>   **Seller Dashboard:** “1234bdb2-a8ed-4fb8-96f9-123456789daa”

What does it mean? How to solve this?

I have added same Client ID in `AppManifest.xml` which was created on Seller Dashboard.

Followed this link:

- [How can I avoid errors when submitting my app or add-in to the Office Store?](https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/office-store-submission-faq)